# How do I compete in search engines when my competitors are paying for backlinks?

Tags: seo, backlinks

I have built a site for a client that does tiling, the site I have created is optimized for Google and in very good shape even with Google quality content. I find most of the competition have poor sites with little if any content. but they are always not only on the first page of organic search but the second and third page all at the same time. It is only when I did search on clients backlinks did I discover they are paying for backlinks. I understand one can report this to Google,

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/paidlinks?pli=1

This is something I have not done before, can anyone add some advice as to doing this, and will I need to do it every day until Google acts. What is the normal time scale Google acts on things like this, my client is prepared to pay for adverts but, all in all the competition has paid for hundreds of backlinks and it is a waste of my clients money just paying for adverts aka one click where as competition for far less are availing from the backlinks.

Comment: Your competitors are running a risky business.  Google will probably catch them eventually.

Comment: Buying links is a gross violation of Google's recommendations https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66356?hl=en .  You can report this to Google https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/paidlinks

Answer (score 2):

Nothing beats authentic backlinks and fresh unique content.

This takes longer than paying for backlinks but in a year or so you will have real traction instead of purchased and at that point you will be winning.

One main benefit for this (among many benefits) is the relationships you will build with others online from you reaching out and them coming to you due to fresh content. And these relationships will work in your favors later when you ask for help or trade backlinks.

Also, don’t be afraid to get the ball rolling with some Facebook advertisements. This is a a very cost effective way to start building you brand and getting the word out.

Remember you’re building a reliable and trustworthy brand. You want authenticity and value. It takes time to do this as you build up your reputation in your niche of choice.

That said, with enough money you can potentially buy your reputation and speed up the process but only if you have the knowledgeable staff to backup the claims. This happens in Silicon Valley all the time. But it costs quite a bit of money. So if your rich go for it. Otherwise slow and steady wins the race.